# Zooming UIImageView in a UIScrollView acts weirdly

Tags: ios, imageview, zooming, scrollview

I have the following problem, guys. I have an app that is pretty much like Apple's PhotoScroller. I want to jump from image to image by swiping the screen. I can do that, but I can't zoom the images. Here's the problem - I have an array with images. If the array has only one object inside, there's no problem with zooming. But if there are more images in the array, they acts weirdly when I try to zoom. The image is not being zoomed and it goes where it wants off the screen. Here is my code:

```
int pageWidth = 1024;
int pageHeight = 768;
int counter = 0;

self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight)];

CGRect containerFrame = self.view.frame;
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:containerFrame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

NSMutableArray *all = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[all addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"222.jpg"]];

CGSize scrollSize = CGSizeMake(pageWidth * [all count], pageHeight);
[scrollView setContentSize:scrollSize];



for (UIImage *image in all)
{
    UIImage *pageImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    pageImage = [all objectAtIndex:counter];

    CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(pageWidth * counter, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
    miniScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
    [scrollView addSubview:miniScrollView];

    CGSize miniScrollSize = CGSizeMake(pageImage.size.width, pageImage.size.height);
    [miniScrollView setContentSize:miniScrollSize];

    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageImage.size.width, pageImage.size.height)];
    tempImageView.image = [all objectAtIndex:counter];
    self.imageView = tempImageView;

    miniScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    miniScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    miniScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    miniScrollView.delegate = self;
    miniScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    miniScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    miniScrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    [miniScrollView addSubview:imageView];

    counter ++;
}
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}


-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}
```

Do you have any ideas what's wrong? Because I am trying to get this work almost 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I also worked on such sort of App. The first thing that you can do is to take a separate subclass of your ScrollView so that all the paging and zooming operations can be handled easily. In your scrollView Class, You can take reference from the following code snippet.

```
@interface PhotoScrollView : UIScrollView<UIScrollViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
int finalPhotoWidth;
int finalPhotoHeight;
}


 // to contain image
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImage:(UIImage *)photo
 {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
    // Initialization code

    [self initializeScrollViewWithImage:photo];

    //setting gesture recognizer for single tap
     UITapGestureRecognizer  *singleTapRecognizer    =   [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewSingleTapped:)];
     singleTapRecognizer.delegate    =   self;
     singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired    =   1;
     [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecognizer];


     //setting gesture recognizer for Double tap
     UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
     doubleTapRecognizer.delegate    =   self;
     doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
    [singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];

    singleTapActivated  =   FALSE;

    self.backgroundColor    =   [UIColor blackColor];

    self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    self.maximumZoomScale = 15.0f;
    self.zoomScale = 1.0f;

    self.delegate   =   self;
}
return self;
}


//for sizing the frame by giving height and width
-(void)initializeScrollViewWithImage:(UIImage*)photo
{

finalPhotoWidth = photo.size.width;
finalPhotoHeight = photo.size.height;

//Pre-checking of frame and setting the height and width accordingly

 if (finalPhotoHeight > self.frame.size.height)
 {
    // if photo height is bigger than frame height, re-adjust the photo height and width accordingly

    finalPhotoHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    finalPhotoWidth = (photo.size.width/photo.size.height) * finalPhotoHeight;
}
 if (finalPhotoWidth > self.frame.size.width)
 {
    // if photo width is bigger than frame width, re-adjust the photo height and width accordingly

    finalPhotoWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    finalPhotoHeight = (photo.size.height/photo.size.width) * finalPhotoWidth;
 }
  if (finalPhotoHeight < self.frame.size.height && finalPhotoWidth < self.frame.size.width)
  {
    // if the photo is smaller than frame, increase the photo width and height accordingly

    finalPhotoWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    finalPhotoHeight    =   self.frame.size.height;
  }

  //initialising imageView with the thumbnail photo

  self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photo];
  self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

  //setting frame according to the modified width and height
  if(!isnan(finalPhotoWidth) && !isnan(finalPhotoHeight))
  {
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( (self.frame.size.width - finalPhotoWidth) / 2,    (self.frame.size.height - finalPhotoHeight)/2, finalPhotoWidth,  finalPhotoHeight);

  }

  // setting scrollView properties

  self.contentSize    =   self.imageView.frame.size;

  // add image view to scroll view
  [self addSubview:self.imageView]; 
}

 //to deny the simultaneous working of single and double taps
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{

return NO;
}

// Gesture handleer for single tap gesture
-(void)scrollViewSingleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
 if(!singleTapActivated)
 {
 //do as per requirement
       singleTapActivated  =   TRUE;
 }

else
{
    //do as per requirement
    singleTapActivated  =   FALSE;
}
}


//for zooming after double tapping
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

//to check whether image is zoomed
if (self.zoomScale != 1.0f)
{
    //if image is zoomed, then zoom out


    [self setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( (self.frame.size.width - finalPhotoWidth) / 2, (self.frame.size.height - finalPhotoHeight)/2, finalPhotoWidth,  finalPhotoHeight);

    [self.observer photoZoomStopped];

}
else
{

    // get the point of image which is double tapped
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

    // Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.zoomScale * 4.0f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.maximumZoomScale);

    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it

    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.imageView.frame.size;


    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [self zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}

}

// To re-center the image after zooming in and zooming out
- (void)centerScrollViewContents
{
CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width)
{
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
}
else
{
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height)
{
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
}
else
{
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

//for zooming in and zooming out
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if (self.zoomScale > 1.0f)
{
    [self.observer photoZoomStarted];

    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}
else
{
    self.bouncesZoom    =   NO;

    [self.observer photoZoomStopped];

        // for zooming out by pinching
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

// The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
return self.imageView;
}
```

Please let me know if it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't work. The image goes off the screen again.

Comment: Are you properly re-centering the offsets?

Comment: I am not sure.. how to do that?

Comment: Use the method "centerScrollViewContents" effectively at right place as per your requirement. Are you using custom scroll view or just a scrollview in your controller?